# Loading Queries in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

How to execute queries saved to your PC?

If you're like me and you have just started using SQL Server with the SQL Server Management Studio and just created/saved a complicated query, you might be wondering how you can open and run that query at a later date.

For me, it wasn't completely apparent, but with a few minutes of searching and trial and error, I've found a simple solution.

If anyone else has other solutions please list them below. Thanks.

Comment: Projects can be a useful way of organising queries for reuse

Comment: You could simply associate .sql files with SSMS, then they would open automatically when you double click them.

Answer (score 2):

Seems rather convoluted - what's wrong with just using `File > Open > File`??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the location of your saved query in your file explorer.
2. Drag the desired query into the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
3. The query should automatically load into the viewport.